# Where is the implementation of `MinRankOfClass::convert`?

Tags: kusama

In substrate ranked-collective pallet, we can see the function call.

```rust
let min_rank = T::MinRankOfClass::convert(class);
```

Check the code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/ranked-collective/src/lib.rs#L596).

In the polkadot repo, I can only find the configuration for `type MinRankOfClass`.

```rust
type MinRankOfClass = sp_runtime::traits::Identity;
```

Check the code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/governance/fellowship.rs#L356).

The problem is I still can not find where is the `convert` function implementation which works for fellowship collective(ranked-collective pallet). Could anybody help me out of this? Many thanks.

The reason I need to understand this code is I have to judge whether the rank of a fellowship member is enough to vote a fellowship referendum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_runtime/traits.rs.html#729-733

Just like its name said, identity.

```rs
/// A structure that performs identity conversion.
pub struct Identity;
impl<T> Convert<T, T> for Identity {
    fn convert(a: T) -> T {
        a
    }
}
```